# What are the U and M file markers in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[image]

What do U and M mean in the image? I am using Visual Studio Code and Git. I did some search on the Internet, but I could not find anything on this.

Comment: There exists an issue about using "U" character: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36912

Answer (score 190):

**A** - Added (This is a new file that has been added to the repository)

**M** - Modified (An existing file has been changed)

**D** - Deleted (a file has been deleted)

**U** - Untracked (The file is new or has been changed but has not been added to the repository yet)

**C** - Conflict (There is a conflict in the file)

**R** - Renamed (The file has been renamed)

**S** - Submodule (In repository exists another subrepository)

**T** - Typechange (The file changed from symlink to regular file, or visa versa)

Comment: Anybody else feel like these markers mostly cause anxiety more than anything for any new VS Code user? When do these markers require attention before publishing for example? Hope I'm making sense...

Comment: @Goku the only marker that would require your attention is the Conflict one. All the other markers represent the changes you have made. With the possible exception of Conflict, as this usually happens when pulling in another branch, with code that isn't quite sure where it should be or is sometimes a duplicate.

Comment: What if there's a number in front? For example, I see "1,M" on one file.

Comment: @Octopus This is the number of changes in that file. So, your file would have 1 modification. A file that says "2, C" will have to conflicts.

Comment: @Georgia. Most files don't have a number, just the letter. Apparently, the number represents the number of errors found by the parser. So, don't check in any files with a number beside them.

Comment: And there is a 'S' letter that means submodule

Comment: How do you add the untracked files to the repository?

Answer (score 63):

When you do a `git status` from your command line, it will give you a list of `modified` and `untracked` files that currently exist on your local machine.

The **M** and **U** in this case is just Visual Studio Code syncing up with Git and identifying (very nicely in the UI, I might add) which files have been `modified` and which files are `untracked`.

It\'s just a nice, clear and easy way to look through your workspace and see exactly what your current `git status` is without having to enter the command on the command line.

**Please Note:**

You will only ever see `modified` or `untracked` files highlighted in Visual Studio Code.

If you delete a file, for example, it will just disappear from your workspace, however your `git status`, when executed from the command line, will still include a `deleted` status for that file. But you won\'t see any additional visual representation for this in Visual Studio Code (the file will just not be listed in your workspace any more).

Comment: I'm definitely seeing some shown as deleted when they should just not be there. And `git status` is showing me up to date.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage yes this behaviour has changed in the more recent updates of VSCode.

Answer (score 25):

The 'U' means the files are 'untracked', and 
the 'M' means the files have been 'modified'.

You can use the commands:

`git add -A` - To add all the files to the staging area.

`git commit -m 'message'` - To create a 'snapshot' of the files on the staging area.

Hope this explains what you were trying to figure out.

Comment: Whilst your answer does fix the issue, the OP asked what the U & M markers meant, not how to get rid of them. Perhaps edit your answer to explain it and what your answer means with regards to the OP's question?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain what the U and M means and also gave a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea, you don't necessarily want to add all the files to a git repo. It would be great if git didn't highlight everything, sometimes there are files that you don't actually want in a repo and the git markers become useless noise if they are highlighting the wrong things.

Comment: That was helpful, when you see these markers and you don't know what they are, the very next question is what to do with them? So, your answer was correct and then some. I personally know Git from command line, but not in VSC, so you saved me a lot of headache trying to figure out what to do to add the file to git. I didn't realize you can do everything in the VSC powershell that you could in a desktop command line.

Answer (score 21):

You can disable this by going to: File -> Preferences -> Settings

find: "git.decorations.enabled" and change it to false

If you are not working with git find:  "git.enabled" and change it to false