# What does the S file marker mean in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to use VSCode and I saw this other question explaining the git features of the file manager: [What are U & M file markers in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304195/what-are-u-m-file-markers-in-visual-studio-code)
I learned what U and M mean but some of my folders have the S marker and I don't know what it means. I'm surprised that I can't find anything else online about this! Does anyone know what the "S" means?'

[image: image of file manager with S file markers]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the "S" stands for for ["submodule"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), indicating that this folder corresponds to a [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). A submodule is a Git repository that's inside of another Git repository.

Note that these notations are provided by various components, called SCM providers, that aren't part of Visual Studio Code itself. So what you see depends on which provider you're using for VS Code git extensions.

Answer (score 5):

S - Submodule (This is a Git repo inside of another Git repo)

Other Letters are:

A - Added (This is a new file that has been added to the repository)

M - Modified (An existing file has been changed)

D - Deleted (a file has been deleted)

U - Untracked (The file is new or has been changed but has not been added to the repository yet)

C - Conflict (There is a conflict in the file)

R - Renamed (The file has been renamed)