# What does I file indicator in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

what does `I` file indicator mean in VSCode?
(I purposefully created an error in the file, but when it's not there the `I` indicator is still present)

I know what `M` and `U` stand for, but I did merge two branches, resolved all conflicts and I got this `I` indicator for the first time ever.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56949693/8820629) answer doesn't cover this one unfortunately.

When I do `git add` on it, it changes to `M`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: It shows `"Unmerged paths: both modified: Game.cpp"`, so I guess it is what `I` stands for?

Comment: Yep, looks like a merge conflict.